# "libgjs0c conflicts with libgjs0" error when using dpkg

Tags: dpkg

today I tried to install a dpkg but it fails, it happened when I tried to install kernel, too.

```
mahdi@mahdi-System:~$ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libgjs0_0.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libgjs0.
dpkg: regarding .../libgjs0_0.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb containing libgjs0:
 libgjs0c conflicts with libgjs0
  libgjs0 (version 0.5-1ubuntu2) is to be installed.
dpkg: error processing /home/mahdi/Downloads/libgjs0_0.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libgjs0
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/mahdi/Downloads/libgjs0_0.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> libgjs0c conflicts with libgjs0
> ```

One of the packages that you have already installed conflicts with the package you're trying to install. The packages `libgjs0` and `libgjs0c` both contain `/usr/lib/libgjs.so.0` and assorted dependencies, but these are incompatible versions of the library, because they depend on different Mozilla libraries: [`libgjs0c`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libgjs0c) is linked with [libmozjs 1.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libmozjs185-1.0) whereas [`libjs0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libgjs0) is linked with [xulrunner 1.9](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/xulrunner-1.9.2) (assuming that you're trying to install the package from lucid).

If you're trying to install a binary that's linked against libgjs, you need to have one that's linked against the libraries in your distribution. You may not be able to install a `.deb` package from an out-of-date PPA or a third-party source intended for Debian. Either grab a package that works on the Ubuntu release you're running, or recompile the source package against your Ubuntu release.